# Considering HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment while creating a custom panel

Tags: wpf, xaml, alignment, panel

I am trying to create a custom panel in wpf. Here the doubts I have,

- How do I consider the
  HorizontalAlignment and
  VerticalAlignment factors while
  placing the items within my panel.
  Should I check for these flags in my
  ArrangeOverride method ??
- Consider
  that I want to write a WrapPanel
  clone. If the panel's width is set to
  "Auto", how do I get the actual width
  of the panel to arrange my child
  items. I always get the
  ActualWidth/ActualHeight as 0. Am I
  missing something???

Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not you act on Horizontal and/or Vertical Alignment is up to you. It would be bad if a vertical StackPanel would consider the VerticalAlignment of a child.

You should call the Measure() method on each Child control. That will give you the desired size.

Answer (score 2):

To implement your own panel, you need to implement `MeasureOverride` and `ArrangeOverride`.  During layout, things are being figured out so the final values are not yet available.  To get started, use the `Size` argument passed to you in `MeasureOverride` which is the available size.  You could end up using more or less than this amount.  That depends on the layout behavior of your panel.  No matter what you do, you have to call `Measure` on all your children and you can of course use that information in your calculations.

If you have some specific panel behavior you want to implement but don't want to handle a large number of special cases, then you can give your children all the space they request in the direction you are not stacking and let your children lay themselves out using sub-panels if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to consider
  HorizontalAlignment and
  VerticalAlignment. These properties
  are used internally by
  FrameworkElement and take effect
  automatically.
- The single argument of
  ArrangeOverride will give you a size,
  which parent allowed for your panel.
  You must arrange children within this
  area. If you mean that "Auto" is a size to place all panel's children, you must compute and return it from MeasureOverride.

And don't forget to use InternalChildren instead of Children.